# Local database choice (Windows Phone 8.1 application)

Tags: c#, database, database-design, windows-phone-8.1

I am in the process of making a relatively complex Windows Phone 8.1 application and I need a way to store data from server's database into a local database. Data from server is retrieved in JSON format via API. What are my options here? I've tried SQLite database controlled by sqlite-net but it lacks key features such as foreign keys support and 64bit support (?). 
What other choices do I have?
Local database is used in order to give the user ability to work offline and later sync the data from local database with server's database.

Answer (score 0):

How many choices? Not many. Local databases for Windows Store apps is a sensitive topic.

You can use foreign keys in sqlite-net if you use the extensions: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

There is also Lex.DB which supports concurrent R/W and also has a very clean and easy to handle API: http://lexblog.azurewebsites.net/intro-to-lex-db/

I don't really see the benefit of x64 support for a Windows Phone application - especially since these devices have an ARM architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, could you explain what is the difference between deploying an app as AnyCPU or ARM to a consumer? Will app deployed as ARM be able to run on all phones, tablets etc.?

Comment: @Millkovac: Yes. The app will run on all devices. The Windows Runtime API takes care for that. That's the beauty of the app store. You can create universal apps using a unified API that will run across all Windows 8+ powered devices which includes phones, tablets and PCs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/)  by Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. You can install it to your project by visual studio NuGet Package Manager.

Using SQLitePCL is very easy. This library truly mimics the C/C++ interface of SQLite. You can find the details of the interfaces here: https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html